# R: removing column by name in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
mydata <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x1 = c(2.5, 2.3, 2.2, 1.2), x2 = c(2.3, 2.3, 9.3, 2.4))
> mydata
  y  x1  x2
1 1 2.5 2.3
2 2 2.3 2.3
3 3 2.2 9.3
4 4 1.2 2.4
```

I would like to remove the column `y` from `mydata`. So I use the following command:

```
> mydata[, -which(names(mydata) %in% c("y"))]
   x1  x2
1 2.5 2.3
2 2.3 2.3
3 2.2 9.3
4 1.2 2.4
```

However, if I only have 2 columns, then using the above command results in a vector:

```
mydata2 <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x1 = c(2.5, 2.3, 2.2, 1.2))
> mydata2[, -which(names(mydata2) %in% c("y"))]
[1] 2.5 2.3 2.2 1.2
```

Instead, I would like the output to be:

```
   x1 
1 2.5 
2 2.3 
3 2.2 
4 1.2
```

How do I remove the `y` column by name and keep the result in a data.frame format with the original column name?

Comment: just use mydata$y <- NULL

Comment: Use `drop = FALSE`, `mydata2[, names(mydata2) != "y", drop = FALSE]`

Comment: The real kicker is that if you remove the `,`, it works just like you want it to, `mydata2[-which(names(mydata2) %in% c("y"))]`